# What is the purpose of Intelligence?

Tags: succubox

I have 30 points in Intelligence, but I can't really see the purpose of it. Does it do anything or is it there just to waste skill points?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It increases experience gained from an enemy.

This can be seen in [combat.js](http://www.glaielgames.com/succubox/combat.js) which shows:

```
data.experience.value += exp_per_enemy() * data.intelligence.value
```

meaning experience gained scales with intelligence.

**Note:** It does *not* increase exp from quantum boxes - the file [lootdrops.js](http://www.glaielgames.com/succubox/lootdrops.js) does not contain "intelligence" at all.

Comment: Does it also scale with the exp gained from quantum boxes?

Comment: @Chippies Doesn't look like it does